# The UIbutton does not resize itself depending on the font size of its title label Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, resize, uifont

I am working on auto layouts and at the same time i need to increase the font size of my button title .I have written a method that increases the font sizes of my UI controls.But when it comes to UI buttons on my view the fonts gets increased but the frame of the button is not increased  to accommodate the font size.

Is there any property for `UIbutton` like `sizethatfits`  that i can use for my button so that it resizes its frame to accommodate the increased font size ?

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;  <--or any other number
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

try this and if you still had a problem let me know!

Comment: applying button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping; will clip the text but it will not increase the frame of my button ? I want the frame of button to be increased as the title font increases

Comment: Try the following for your button.    [self.myButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton sizeToFit];